# Could not get unknown property 'PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION' - Phonegap Build (cordova-plugin-googleplus)

Tags: cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I am getting 'Could not get unknown property 'PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION'' error in Phonegap build when including cordova-plugin-googleplus plugin.

Build is successful if i set this plugin version to 5.2.1. The same problem with facebook and notification plugin.

```
phonegap-plugin-push (1.6.0)
cordova-plugin-facebook4 (1.7.4)
```

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your `cordova-plugin-googleplus`:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus@5.3.1 --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXX
```

or

```
downgrade your-cordova-plugin
```

which doesn't have `PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add the variable, though...

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="^5.3.2">
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="16.0.0" />
</plugin>
```